# Recover modified files in xfs filesystem or find out what happened!

Tags: linux, rhel, xfs

I would like to know if there is a way, I could narrow down what happened on our file system that cause over 700 files to be modified at the exact same date and time making the file sizes 0 bytes for all the files touched. This happened a few months ago. Is there any way to track what might have caused this? The files were all under different folders but under the same root folder in the partition.

The file system is xfs and the storage is mounted from a SAN volume. I don't think there's much chance in recovering the data however would really like to figure out how this happened.